# element locators are not working after proving id, class, xpath, css selector in appium

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

[image: app source login page info showing on appium inspector]

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.widget.EditText)[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.widget.EditText)[1]")).sendKeys("01591142540");

can anyone guide me regarding this declaration?

i have tried to send keys by locating an element and it didn't pass the value. I want some expert to locate the element so that i can send keys and do further operatino

Comment: Can you download the XML and attach it here?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3swLfjxF 
can you please check th html file?